# What is the difference between two coding methods below?

Tags: javascript

```
elem = document.getElementById("demo"); 
elem.innerHTML = x;
```

WHY I CAN NOY WRITE THE CODE ABOVE LIKE THIS:

```
elem = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
elem = x;
```

Comment: you can, it's up to you the developer

Comment: Both will do the same, however I would recommend the first one. `elem = document.getElementById("demo"); ` since is more general and could re-use the same `elem` for some other things, with the second option im attached to the `innerHTML`

Comment: @Woohaik both will NOT do the same thing

Comment: @ControlAltDel ur right, you lost the reference in the second one since its a string and not an object, I meant in both cases you will get the value of the innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

Understand that variable names are just pointers to data in memory

If you understand this you'll be a long way to understanding that in the top, where elem is a label for an HTMLElement, it will set the innerHTML of the element. In the bottom elem is just a string. But more than that, when you set elem to x, you are just setting a new value in the label, not changing the element.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same thing. the first one:

```
elem = document.getElementById("demo"); 
elem.innerHTML = x;
```

`elem` is now an object, an object that is referencing the Element with the `demo` ID.
the next line you are swapping the current value of `innerHTML` to whatever is the value of `x`;

The second one:

```
elem = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
elem = x;
```

The `elem` is a string, the HTML string that is inside the `demo` element ID is now saved on `elem`.
The second line replaces the string inside `elem` with the value of `x`, however the innerHTML of the `demo` element remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
// stores reference to DOM element #demo
elem = document.getElementById("demo");

// changes #demo innerHTML to "x" -- affects the DOM
elem.innerHTML = x;




// stores #demo content as a string
elem = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;

// changes the string to "x" -- does not affect the DOM
elem = x;
```